# Keynote URL Scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme, keynote

Does anybody know how can I modify my Keynote App to add an URL Scheme? I have read a lot on internet that I have to enter on the info.plist of my Keynote App, but I don't know how to do that, and also I don't know how to add an URL Scheme to my Keynote App. Please, I really need your help. Thanks a lot

Comment: From what I am reading, Keynote does not have a url scheme anymore?

Comment: Yeah, Keynote doesn't have a URL Scheme, that is why I'm asking how to modify the app, enter on the info.plist and HOW TO ADD an URL Scheme.

Comment: You can't modify an app (unless you are talking about a jailbroken environment).